# Шифрование файлов алгоритмом Blowfish

Tags: c#, winforms, blowfish

Разбираюсь с алгоритмом шифрования `Blowfish`, хочу разработать программу, которая должна осуществлять шифрование и дешифрование файлов. На сайте нашел исходный код https://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html. Не могу найти пример использования этой библиотеки... Может уже кто-то реализовывал Blowfish и сможет мне помочь?

Comment: Угадайте, на каком языке нужно задавать вопросы на русском отделении Stackoverflow. Подсказка: посмотрите на другие вопросы.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что me does not google translate speak, me suggest your again trying into russian tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение задачи:

```
namespace Blowfish_WF
{
public partial class Blowfish : Form
{
    public Blowfish()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BlowFish bf = new BlowFish("04B915BA43FEB5B6");

        string cipherText = "";

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(textBox1.Text))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
            while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
            {
                cipherText = bf.Encrypt_CBC(temp.GetString(b));
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(cipherText);

        string plainText = bf.Decrypt_CBC(cipherText);
        MessageBox.Show(plainText);

    }

    private void Blowfish_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "04B915BA43FEB5B6";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Возьмите готовую реализацию: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Опен сорс (MIT лицензия), Blowfish есть в списке поддерживаемых алгоритмов. Можете или использовать библиотеку целиком, или вырезать из нее именно Blowfish (не забудьте только оставить копирайты и кусок лицензии от оригинальной).

Comment: готовые алгоритмы я находил, только не могу найти документацию по их использованию